# Add CSS class to empty paragraphs

Tags: css, ckeditor5

Is there a way to add a css class name to empty paragraphs in ckeditor so I can target them with css?

Empty paragraphs in ckeditor are not really empty because they contain a `br` tag so I can not use `:empty` to target them.

Comment: Could you include some code? Because this isn't possible with purely css but maybe there are some ways around it.

Comment: @Under_Koen I am not asking about a pure css solution, but a solution where ckeditor marks the empty paragraphs with a emptyParagraph  class or attribute.

Comment: Do you need to target them in a literal CSS stylesheet, or do you just need a selector you can pass to `querySelectorAll` or a similar API?

Comment: Anything  I use to apply a specific style to the paragraph would be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: ckeditor empty paragraph]

From what I can see, the good thing is that those `<br>` inside empty paragraphs have an attribute which makes them easy to target.

In the future, you might use a pure CSS solution like this one.

```
p:has(> br[data-cke-filler="true"]) {
    /* styles here */
}
```

For now, you either have to style the 
 directly.
Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, maybe applying css to the `<br>` would suffice.

```
br[data-cke-filler="true"] {
    /* styles here */
}
```

And if you are able to run **javascript** in **ckeditor**. This can easely be done today.

Examples : with jQuery

```
$( "p:has(br[data-cke-filler="true"])" ).addClass( "MyEmptyParagraphsClass" );
```

or

```
$( "br[data-cke-filler="true"]" ).parent().addClass( "MyEmptyParagraphsClass" );
```

Example : with Native Javascript

```
var brs = Document.querySelectorAll("br[data-cke-filler="true"]");

brs.forEach(function(br) {
  br.classList.add("MyEmptyParagraphsClass");
});
```

Comment: That is my current plan, if anything else fails. But then I have to run this again each time the user edits anything in the document. And I fear running this each time the user hits a key on the keyboard might be expensive.

Comment: @MTilsted
The function really shouldn't be too expensive to execute.
Looking back at it, your selector would probably be better as `br[data-cke-filler="true"]:not(.MyEmptyParagraphsClass)` This way you only select elements you didn't applied the class to already.
Then it's just about finding the right event to bind the function to. Ideally it would be a mutation observer (changes to DOM : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), but it might be simpler to use the "enter" keystroke or a regular time interval

Comment: also, what style are you trying to apply to the emtpy paragraphs ? are you sure you can't apply it to the `<br>` element ? negative margins, changing the display attribute etc. Maybe you can hack your solution out.

Comment: What I really need, is to apply a style, to the paragraph, following the empty paragraph. Not to the empty paragraph itself. Something like .MyEmptyParagraphsClass + p { text-indent:0; }

Answer (score 0):

**In CKEditor 4**, you can have a [configuration file](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_configuration.html).

And you can add the [custom config with the options here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-customConfig).

In your case, you might need these options :

```
config.ignoreEmptyParagraph = false;
config.fillEmptyBlocks = false; // Prevent filler nodes in all empty blocks.
```

**Meanwhile in CKEditor 5**, you can try these documentations about `Block Widget` :

- [Adding a css class to block elements](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/deep-dive/conversion/conversion-extending-output.html#adding-a-css-class-to-block-elements)
- [Inline and block content](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/deep-dive/conversion/conversion-introduction.html#inline-and-block-content)

Comment: That is for ckeditor 4. It does not work for ckeditor 5. Ckeditor 5 really need those filler br tags. Otherwise the editor breaks.

Comment: @MTilsted Have you tried [this documentation for Adding a Class to Block Elements](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/deep-dive/conversion/conversion-extending-output.html#adding-a-css-class-to-block-elements) ? This is in CKEditor 5